# How to process dd-created disk image, which is corrupted (disk died during dumping)

Tags: linux, hard-disk, data-recovery, dd, disk-image

I have a laptop with HDD which had issues with booting (windows10). I assumed that Windows just failed some way.

I've booted from LinuxLiveUSB and tried to dump the disk using `dd`. DD failed on 85GB because of I/O error. I've read that it is sign of bad block, so I've used `NOERROR` flag next time.

During that process `dd` now throws only I/O errors. I've checked disk in `fdisk -l`, but see only one partition (was 4 before the whole operation) with message that there was no other partition or something (sorry I can't remember correctly).

For the next reboot to LiveUSB, `fdisk` detect no `sda` whatsoever. So I think, disk is dead.

I still have 270GB image (closed DD because of never-ending I/O errors) of 1TB disk. I want to recover data from this image, but neither `OSFMount` on Windows nor `losetup`/`kpartx` can mount Windows partition from this image (`OSFmount` just hangs and linux tools do nothing).

Is there any process to prepare the image in a way to read the data from it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should have used `ddrescue` instead of dd because it's capable of skipping bad blocks properly and the resulting image will become a valid disk image, see https://superuser.com/a/1075837 for more info.

Secondly, if the resulting disk image is severely damaged you must use file restore utilities however the Linux ones are quite weak, e.g. `testdisk` and `photorec`. I would highly recommend using R-Studio Undelete because it's the most reliable and powerful tool for dealing with disk images and deleted files.